# Create a Cloud with PHP, Mysql, Js

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a Cloud with Php, Mysql and Js.
The Question:
At the moment my cloud is reading with PHP the files from a Folder on the Server.
I looked and as i understood Nextcloud saves the File also on the Server in a Folder but the information it takes from the Database like "location, name, size.." and wen you download the File it reads from the Folder on the Server. My Teacher told me that it is also an Option to save Files as a BLOB on the SQL Server that youn only have 1 Place with everything and not 2 (SQL Server with information and Fileserver with Files).
Whats the best option?

Comment: Is this your homework we should do for you? That is not what SO is for. We would not do the work for you. Please clarify your question and add your code otherwise.

Comment: No it is not a Homework ist private. The Question is: is it better to write Data in a SQL Server or is it better to have the Data on a Dataserver and the information of the data in a SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience has generally been that "there's one specialized form of database that's especially well-suited for storing large data-objects under a hierarchy of keys, and that database is called a *file system."*  Many parts of the system are highly-tuned to support "file systems."  Web servers are classically equipped to deliver them to users.  SQL databases, on the other hand, often have difficulty storing such objects.

However, I never want the user to be able to *arbitrarily* troll through my collection of files, so in my system designs I'll restrict them to random strings (called "nonces") which I look up in the database to obtain the name of the actual file where the resource itself is stored ... which the user never sees.  This makes the data private, and it also enables me to implement rules and to gather statistics.  Now, working together, both SQL and the file-system are doing what each of them does best.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that it is better to store the file on the filesystem and store metadata like path, filename, size ... in a database.

But this is my experience in most cases, there are sometimes requirements where it is better to store the (binary)file in a database.

Your teacher is with his opinion not wrong. My personal opinion is, that a (binary)file should be located on the filesystem. But the teachers argument with the one place is correct but when you want to open the file, you have to extract the file every time from the database and that could be cumbersome.

The solution (should) always depends on the requirement.